# Copy member function with template class

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my member function.

My goal is to create a copy of my set, and return a pointer to it.

```
            template <class T>
            class Set
            {
            public:
                Set(int length = 0);     //Default constructor
                ~Set();              //Defualt Destructor
                int size();          //Return how many elements are in set
                bool contains(T test);   //Searches set for T
                bool add(T adding);      //Adds T to set, repeats are denied
                bool remove(T removing); //Attempts to remove T
                T** elements();      //Returns a pointer to the set
                T** copy();          //Creates a copy of the set, and returns a pointer to it
                T &operator[](int sub);  //Overload subscript

            private:
                T** set;        //Pointer to first of set
                int setSize;        //Int holding amount of Elements available
                int holding;        //Elements used
                void subError();    //Handles Subscript out of range
                void adder();       //returns a copy with +1 size
            };
```

and here's my constructor and copy function:

```
            template <class T>
            Set<T>::Set(int length) //Default constructor
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    set[i] = new T;
                }
                setSize = length;
                holding = 0;
            }

            template <class T>
            T** Set<T>::copy()  //Creates a copy of the set, and returns a pointer to it
            {
                T** setCopy;
                for(int i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
                {
                    setCopy[i] = new T;
                    *setCopy[i] = *set[i];
                }
                return setCopy;
            }
```

There errors I'm getting ar eerror error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'setCopy' used
and C4700: uninitialized local variable 'temp' used
I've tried various ways of dereffencing and such, but I'm getting nowhere with it.

Comment: Belaying the fact the very premise of that method is a terrible idea, `T** setCopy = new T*[setSize]` might just you closer. You should also consider using `setCopy[i] = new T(*(set[i]));` as being the only statement within the loop, though as I said, this method has no business even being exposed. If your goal is to create a copy of your set, then create a copy of the **`Set<T>`**, not just a snapshot of the underlying pointer array. Also, this class has dynamic members and no copy-constructor or assignment operator overload, so you're literally playing with an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

Firstly, you need to initialise your `setCopy` variable before you use it.

```
 T** setCopy = new (T*)[setSize]
```

might be what you want; this says that `setCopy` points to an array of `setSize` pointers-to-`T`. Only after that can you tell it that ever member of `setCopy` points to an array of `T`. (You need to do the same in your default constructor too).

However, if what you want is to create a copy of your set, then instead of writing a `copy` method, you should write a *copy constructor*, and an *assignment operator*, so that you can write

```
Set<int> set2 = set1;
```

and have it do the right thing.

Comment: I see...  Ya, this is the first time I'm using templates. I just want a pointer I can pass to the array, not a point to arrays. Thanks for the clarification. I should be able to get it done.

Comment: @NarayanaJamesEmery: Tip: An array is not a pointer.  A pointer to an array is usually just a pointer to the first object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

setCopy is actualy un uninitialized...think about
after `T** setCopy;`
where it's point to?

Comment: wouldn't T** setCopy point to a pointer, which `setCopy[i] = new T;` by dereferencing with [i] make a dynamic T?

And that makes me curious how the normal set worked;